# react router getting the right display page when click button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a question regrading to react. I have a IconButton (Material UI) I want to click this button and it will redirect to the specific help page.

For example:

1. local:3000/education. When I clicked button it will redirect something like local:3000/education/support page.
2. local:3000/data. It redirect to something like data/support page.
   ...etc more pages

I am stuck, I am not sure how to implement the button onClick function to redirect to the right support page. I am thinking using react-router, I have did some research we can use 'params' and 'history' parameters from the props?  Thank you

Please give me some good advice and right direction thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => history.push(`${pathname}/support`)}>
        support page
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I dont want to create like 20 support page for each /${pathname}, do you know how to generate a support page for each path tho?

Answer (score 0):

localhost:3000/education.
If you use history.push("/support"), It redirects to localhost:3000/support.
But If you use history.push("support"), It redirects to localhost:3000/education/support

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks